# Repair options of a (really) Broken HFS+ "Invalid extent entry" volume?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, hfs+, fsck-hfs

I have an un-mountable external 2TB harddisk, formattet HFS+, one "usable" partition, containing a set of my backups. It won't show in Finder, it won't repair in disk utility, it won't repair on the commandline:

```
$ diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk2s2
Started file system verification on disk2s2 zuhauseBackup
Verifying file system
Volume is already unmounted
Performing fsck_hfs -fn -x /dev/rdisk2s2
Journal needs to be replayed but volume is read-only
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume
Invalid extent entry
The volume   could not be verified completely
File system check exit code is 8
Restoring the original state found as unmounted
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 8

$ diskutil list /dev/disk2
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS NameNotShown            2.0 TB     disk2s2
$
```

(The above `NameNotShown` is, in reality, shown correctly).

Linux `hfsplus`-fsck also give the same error as the macOS tools (it appears to be exactly the same tool):

```
$ sudo fsck_hfs /dev/rdisk2s2
** /dev/rdisk2s2
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-522.100.5).
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
   Invalid extent entry
(4, 0)
** The volume   could not be verified completely.
$
```

Mounting it to a Linux PC I can see some files in the Backup-Directories, yet most "important" directories only show up as files of size 0.

The above **`Invalid extent entry`** seems to be the culprit. Any ideas how to get around this and possibly fix my volume, hopefully at least recover the files?

Answer (score 1):

Though it still cannot handle APFS, the single best 'fixit' app for HFS+ has always been [DiskWarrior](https://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/). idk whether they do a free trial.

Failing that, you're into 'file scavenger' apps, which are going to be poor on a drive full of hardlinks.

Comment: I had already tried Micromat's TechTool 13, but that wasn't able to help. Do you think DiskWarrioer does a better job?

Comment: Yup TTP was never a patch on DW, ever (even if it used to be the Apple Genius in-house tool)

Comment: +1 on *DiskWarrior*. It’s saved my bacon several times over the years and they deserve all my money.

Comment: **Very important note:** Do *NOT* turn on or try to use your drive anymore until you are ready to recover it. Any additional access increases chances for further corruption.